jQuery SET Data Attribute Val on Click
Let's say I have an on click jquery function, how do I go about SETTING a data-ATTR="VALUE" ON CLICK?
For example:
data-theme="lightmode"

On click, I want to set this value of data-theme to "darkmode"
This data-theme is added in the  of page.

Duplicate: How to set data attributes in HTML elements.

How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?. In this case, it should hardly have been a time-consuming exercise - a simple google search of your question's title would have got you most or all of the way to the solution. We're happy to help people where necessary, but there's very little point in you waiting for a human to tell you what a search engine would have told you a lot faster.
